# How to "loop" wait loading "webbrowser" component before moving to the next item?

Tags: vb.net

I'm reading the contents of a textbox, and using a "For Each loop" to pass the string in sequence to the url localhost containing the php code:

```
$var = $_GET["nts"];
echo $var;
```

So far everything is fine, the problem is that the 'loop' does not wait for full loading the document 'Web Browser', thus for example, I can not make a parse the HTML document of each string, the idea is to launch a string in 'Web Browser' and wait for the complete loading the document 'Web Browser' to launch the second string, and so on.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim tb As String = TextBox1.Text

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb) Then

        MsgBox("Null")

    Else

        For Each t As String In tb

            If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t)) Then

            Else

                WebBrowser1.Navigate(String.Concat("http://localhost/a/as.php?nts=", t))

            End If

        Next

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted



End Sub
```

Comment: How about if you create a new webbrowser every time, add a handler to the `DocumentCompleted` event and then you handle the parsing from there?

Comment: how would that be? you could give me an example of the code?

Comment: Put this somewhere below "Public Class Form1": `Dim WebBrowserList As New List(Of WebBrowser)`. --- **Line 1 in your loop:** `WebBrowserList.Add(New WebBrowser)` --- **Line 2:** `AddHandler WebBrowserList(WebBrowserList.Count - 1).DocumentCompleted, AddressOf WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` --- **Line 3:** `WebBrowserList(WebBrowserList.Count - 1).Navigate(Url here)`.